# SSL certificate Issue with SVN

Tags: ssl, svn, sonarqube, collabnet

Getting the below error when I am building the extension from the below given URL

Maven goals - -DskipTests=true clean install sonar:sonar

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.3:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project : The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x
>   -w src/main/java/xxx.java] failed: svn: E230001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'https://xxxxxxd01.xx.com/svn/project/trunk/xx/xxxx.java' [ERROR] svn:
>   E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate
>   issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted

Solutions Tried : Accepted the certificate through command line and Manually ,worked first time but after system restart its not working again

Answer (score 1):

Add the following command line parameters to the command Sonarqube runs:

- `--non-interactive`
- `--trust-server-cert`

The error `svn: E230001: server ssl certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted updating` means that you have non-trusted SSL certificate installed in the VisualSVN Server. Furthermore, the certificate was given to the hostname, which is differs than you use to reach your repository. The best way to solve the issue would be to install signed SSL certificate on the server. You should also make sure you have entered correct hostname in the URL.

Comment: Hello Thank you for suggesting, I am running this command through Jenkins Job. After building the extension I have specified the maven goal as  -DskipTests=true clean install sonar:sonar Couldyou please let me know where to run the above mentioned commands